# What is a policy in reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I've seen such words as:

> A policy defines the learning agent's way of behaving at a given time. Roughly
>   speaking, a policy is a mapping from perceived states of the environment to actions to be taken when in those states.

But still didn't fully understand. What exactly is a policy in reinforcement learning?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The definition is correct, though not instantly obvious if you see it for the first time. Let me put it this way: *a policy is an agent's strategy*.

For example, imagine a world where a robot moves across the room and the task is to get to the target point (x, y), where it gets a reward. Here:

- A room is an *environment*
- Robot's current position is a *state*
- A *policy* is what an agent does to accomplish this task:

  - dumb robots just wander around randomly until they accidentally end up in the right place (policy #1)
  - others may, for some reason, learn to go along the walls most of the route (policy #2)
  - smart robots plan the route in their "head" and go straight to the goal (policy #3)

Obviously, some policies are better than others, and there are multiple ways to assess them, namely *state-value function* and *action-value function*. The goal of RL is to learn the best policy. Now the definition should make more sense (note that in the context time is better understood as a state):

*A policy defines the learning agent's way of behaving at a given time.*

#### Formally

More formally, we should first define *Markov Decision Process* (MDP) as a tuple (`S`, `A`, `P`, `R`, `y`), where:

- `S` is a finite set of states
- `A` is a finite set of actions
- `P` is a state transition probability matrix (probability of ending up in a state for each current state and each action)
- `R` is a reward function, given a state and an action
- `y` is a discount factor, between 0 and 1

Then, a policy `π` is a probability distribution over actions given states. That is the likelihood of every action when an agent is in a particular state (of course, I'm skipping a lot of details here). This definition corresponds to the second part of your definition.

I highly recommend [David Silver's RL course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqYmG7hTraZBiG_XpjnPrSNw-1XQaM_gB) available on YouTube. The first two lectures focus particularly on MDPs and policies.

Answer (score 29):

In plain words, in the simplest case, a policy `π` is a function that takes as input a state `s` and returns an action `a`. That is: `π(s) → a`

In this way, the policy is typically used by the agent to decide what action `a` should be performed when it is in a given state `s`.

Sometimes, the policy can be *stochastic* instead of *deterministic*. In such a case, instead of returning a unique action `a`, the policy returns a probability distribution over a set of actions.

In general, the goal of any RL algorithm is to learn an optimal policy that achieve a specific goal.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a succinct answer: a policy is the 'thinking' of the agent. It's the mapping of when you are in some state `s`, which action `a` should the agent take now? You can think of policies as a lookup table:

```
state----action----probability/'goodness' of taking the action
  1         1                     0.6
  1         2                     0.4
  2         1                     0.3
  2         2                     0.7
```

If you are in state 1, you'd (assuming a greedy strategy) pick action 1. If you are in state 2, you'd pick action 2.